# Origen de colorado como sinónimo de rojo

Tags: significado, sinónimos, colores

El término [*colorado*](https://dle.rae.es/colorado?m=form) como sinónimo de rojo es bastante conocido. Su etimología viene clara en el DLE

> Del lat. colorātus, de colorāre 'colorar'

Haciendo el seguimiento de significados, colorar tiene como tercera acepción

> intr. desus. Dicho de algunos frutos: colorear (‖ tomar el color encarnado).

Por lo visto, desde colorear viene el origen 'rojizo' de la palabra, pero colorear es:

> dar color a una cosa o teñirla

Pero sería cualquier color (del rojo al violeta pasando por todo el espectro lumínico y sumen al blanco y al negro). ¿Cuál es el origen que el rojo sea el sinónimo de colorado?

Comment: También me lo he preguntado, a ver como se explique. ¿Quizás fuese así en el latín?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aparentemente este *colorado* como "rojo" viene de bastante tiempo atrás (se encuentra en el Siglo de Oro y antes). Lo que sigue es una conjetura mía.

Ya en latín *color* tenía el sentido (que todavía tiene actualmente) de "complexión, tonalidad de la piel", y en castellano existe ya desde hace siglos la expresión *ponerse colorado* con el sentido de "ruborizarse". Mi conjetura es que esta asociación es la fuente del significado de *colorado* como "rojo". La progresión sería así: primero se habla de *colorarse* queriendo decir "acentuársele a uno el color de la cara, ruborizarse, subírsele a uno los colores"; más adelante se empieza a utilizar el participio, *colorado*, como sinónimo de "ruborizado", y quizá también por extensión como sinónimo de "maduro, rojo" (referido a un fruto), cosa probable porque el símil entre frutas maduras y mejillas ruborizadas es bastante obvio; finalmente, *colorado* pasa a significar "rojo" independientemente de si se trata del rojo natural de las facciones de alguien ruborizado o el color rojo de cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: Perhaps, the term is a hybridization of Calorado (heated, hot) and Colorado (colored). Someone who is hot and turns red says "estoy Calorado" and someone responds by refering  to their beat red color and says "Si, eres muy Colorado."

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, la palabra *rojo* se terminó imponiendo a finales del Siglo de Oro o después sobre palabras como *colorado* o *escarlata*. En este [artículo](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-51268345) dan a entender como las palabras habituales para describir el primer color del espectro visual eran *bermejo*, *colorado* o *encarnado*. En particular el término *colorado* ya lo utiliza Alfonso X en 3 escritos y para una mejor comparación, una Biblia ladinada (en judeo-español) transcrita en 1400, muestra 4 veces la palabra colorado, que en traducciones recientes aparece como púrpura o rojo.

El CORDE trae como único caso de rojo en 1352 hasta 1500, contra más de 300 casos de colorado, así pues, en realidad *rojo* habría sido el sinónimo de *colorado* antes de desplazarlo en el habla cotidiana.

Búsqueda en el REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA: Banco de datos (CORDE) [en línea]. Corpus diacrónico del español. http://www.rae.es