# What does Colorado really mean in Spanish?

Tags: definiciones, colores

I was surprised to discover *colorado* means red colored or red. *Color* means color in Spanish and the ending  *-ado* is equivalent to the ending -ed in English. Putting the two together should mean colored as would the Portuguese word *colorido*, a neighboring language. Just as the word bearded *Barbado* is formed by joining *barba*, beard, and -*ado*, -ed in both Spanish and Portuguese. Red or red colored, simply makes no sense at all.

I've Googled around and found that all the results claim it means red or red colored, but when I tried to translate colored using Google translate, it also included colored as one of the translations. This is remarkably odd. Could it be a remnant of an older dialect of Spanish?

[image]

Comment: There is an interesting discussion about the origins of this on this very site https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32838/origen-de-colorado-como-sin%c3%b3nimo-de-rojo It is the top hit if you search the site for _colorado_.

Answer (score 2):

*Color* is not a verb, it is a noun. The verb that refers to the action of coloring is *colorear*.

The participle of the verb *colorear* is *coloreado* (not *colorado*).

These are two different words:

- **Coloreado** means colored as the description in the question
- **Colorado** means reddish color

*Colorado* and *coloreado* are not synonymous.

Comment: Google gives colored as one of it's definitions in its screen capture.

Comment: Spanish is a consistent language, but I don't see red at all.

Comment: If you read on top is written "adjective", "coloreado" is a participle, "colorado" is an adjective. In this translation, the participle "coloreado" doesn't appear. You should try Google: "coloreado".

Comment: @ATL_DEV BTW, the translation colorado = coloured is wrong

Comment: Yes, but where did the "red" come in? For instance, Rosado, also means red, but "rosa", meaning rose or red, is part of the word. I'm trying to figure out the etymology of colorado.

Comment: According to etymology online (https://www.etymonline.com/word/colorado)
U.S. state (organized as a territory 1861, admitted as a state 1876), named for the river, Spanish Rio Colorado, from colorado "ruddy, reddish," literally "colored," past participle of colorar "to color, dye, paint," from Latin colorare "to color, to get tanned," from color "color of the skin, color in general" (see color (n.)).

Comment: colorado is definitely reddish in color and coloreado is coloured or colored. No doubt at all. This answer is spot on.

Comment: Colorar y colorear son sinónimos. Como se puede comprobar por el primer significado de ambos que da el DRAE: 1. tr. Dar color a una cosa o teñirla. Teniendo esto presente, no entiendo tu respuesta, para mí es totalmente incorrecta, incluyendo la última afirmación.

Comment: Puede que colorear y colorar sean sinónimos, pero colorado y coloreado no lo son.